# How can I calculate the change in velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, velocity, vectors

"A runner runs at 4 m/s on a circular track constantly. A and B are opposite points on the track, so A is the starting point and B is halfway around the track.  Calculate his change in velocity from A to B, if any."

I know that velocity is a vector, and therefore has a direction.  Logically his change to me is -8 m/s.  As -4 - 4 = -8, but is the change 8 or -8?  Or is it 0 because 4 - 4 = 0?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: You should look up the definitions of *velocity* and *speed*.

Comment: Yeah, velocity is "the speed of an object in a given direction" and speed is just the rate an object moves.  That makes velocity a vector right?  Sorry just not catching on to what you're trying to get at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your axes in such a way that the runner has a speed of 4m/s in the y direction in point A, the the velocity in point A is:

$V_A = 4 \, \text{m/s} \, \hat{y} + 0 \, \text{m/s} \, \hat{x}$

Your runner must have a speed of -4m/s in the y direction in point B, you get the velocity:

$V_B = -4 \, \text{m/s} \, \hat{y} + 0 \, \text{m/s} \, \hat{x}$

The speed in the x direction is unchanged.

Regardless of choice of axis the equation should be: $V_A + change = V_B = -V_A$, so the change in this case must always be equal to $-2 \cdot V_A$

You initial guess of -8m/s, with regard to the magnitude of the velocity change, is correct if you place your initial vector along with one of the axes of your coordinate system of choice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change of velocity is definitely -8m/s, according to vector summation.
Magnitude of change of velocity is 8m/s. '-' sign indicates that the change is taking in the other direction,i.e. in the direction opposite to the initial direction. 4-4=0 is the change in speed , not velocity